# SQL: select only data from one column, for which one of the value from second column is x

Tags: sql, database

I have a problem which I can't describe without explaining this on this example:
So there are 2 columns like:

```
X     Y
A     2
A     1
A     3
B     3
C     2
A     1
D     2
B     1
B     3
C     1
A     1
D     3
D     1
```

and now I would like to select only that data from X, where one of the values from Y is 2.
So my output should look like:

```
    X     Y
    A     2
    A     1
    A     3
    C     2
    A     1
    D     2
    C     1
    A     1
    D     3
    D     1
```

because Y=2 for X=B doesn't exist in the main table.
My question is what is the query for this operation? I tried something with CASE WHEN but something didn't fix for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT X FROM Table WHERE X IN (SELECT X FROM Table WHERE Y=2)
```

OR Try

```
SELECT t1.X FROM Table t1 
INNER JOIN Table t2 ON t1.X = t2.X
WHERE t2.Y = 2
```

Comment: And now how can I remove from the output those rows with for example Y=1? Y=!1 in the end isn't appropriate.

Comment: then its simple `SELECT X FROM Table WHERE Y=2`

Comment: No, not like this, I mean that only one type of values should be removed like Y=1, not Y=3

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery:

```
SELECT X FROM table WHERE X IN (SELECT X FROM table WHERE Y = 2);
```